# How do I learn an external bluetooth device's Vendor and Product IDs?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, android-10, external-keyboard

Recently, I purchased an external Bluetooth keyboard (Rii i4) for my unrooted AYN Odin device, running on Android 10. I wish I read the reviews beforehand. Said keyboard's keyboard section does not work on certain Android versions, only the trackpad and scroll wheel work. So text input is impossible.

Upon learning that the manufacturer released a firmware update, I headed to their site, only to see the necessary firmware removed from the download section. However, it is still accessible through either a direct download link or the Wayback Machine. I applied the firmware update... And the keyboard got bricked. Doesn't turn on, only the red charging LED works. Contacted the manufacturer, send the bricked device back, and purchased another one.

Now, in an obscure corner of the internet, I found another user telling me that the real problem is a `.kl` file found in `/System/system/usr/keylayout`. The user said to find the file starting with vendor ID, ending with product ID, and to rename it to i.e. `.klbackup`, and the problem will be solved. I don't know if what he/she says has merit, but I would like to try it, at least. Because the keyboard section actually works, too... When the device is turned off and back on, until the message on screen "i4 connected" appears, you can actually press the keyboard letters and they register. But that's just for a few seconds at best.

I don't want to brick this one too. The app called "External Keyboard Helper Pro" wouldn't help. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: "*I found another user telling me*" could you link the source to this? Is it for the same device?